# Access local html and media files using cordova with a local http server on iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, local-files

I have a cordova app that we had to migrate to the new vkwebview plugin for ios.
I am using cordova-plugin-sync to download media to the server. I used to access this using file://. as the access method but this is no longer allowed.

So I have installed httpd local server.|

But I cannot access the correct path.
When I console out the downloaded path I get:

```
"Users/CNNECT/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/6C648138-5139-4489-AF7F-56A609FFBAED/data/Containers/Data/Application/18EB7317-B2B9-4FD3-84E4-F19911ADB15A/Library/NoCloud"
```

So I tried to assign this full path so that http://localhost:8080 resolves there, but the assets that are saved as "456/media.jpg" dont display when I try to reference them using http://localhost:8080/456/media.jpg

If I try and hardcode the path:

```
"Users/CNNECT/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/6C648138-5139-4489-AF7F-56A609FFBAED/data/Containers/Data/Application/18EB7317-B2B9-4FD3-84E4-F19911ADB15A/Library/NoCloud/456/media.jpg"
```

It still fails

For ios, what is the pathway that I would use when trying to access locally saved files?

Answer (score 1):

Install this plugin to allow the use of file:// (cordova-ios 6+)

```
 cordova plugin add https://github.com/globules-io/cordova-plugin-ios-xhr
```

Then set your preferences

```
 <preference name="NativeXHRLogging" value="true">
 <preference name="AllowUntrustedCerts"  value="true" />
 <preference name="InterceptRemoteRequests" value="all" />
 <preference name="allowFileAccessFromFileURLs" value="true" />
 <preference name="allowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs" value="true" />
```

Comment: Thanks Eric, I can't confirm if this is correct yet, Cordova needed to be updated to iOS platform 6. This causes a bug in Xcode where I cannot build the platform. I will attempt to resolve that before I mark this as correct